# How can I use table's view bottom refresh twice on UI Testing?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I had a problem that I use bottom refresh from table view, but only the first time works correctly. After the refreshing the table my test is freezing. There's my code:

```
func test_lista(){

    //Entrar a la lista de ofertas
    app.tables.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 2).tap()
    sleep(2)

    //Arrastrar la ultima fila
    app.swipeUp()
    app.swipeUp()
    let cell = app.tables.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 2)
    let start = cell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0))
    let finish = cell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0,dy: -30.0))
    start.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finish)

    app.swipeUp()
    app.swipeUp()
    let cell2 = app.tables.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 4)
    let start2 = cell2.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0))
    let finish2 = cell2.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0,dy: -30.0))
    start2.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finish2)

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just only to make add this line to my table view's method:

```
    self.offerTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: lastIndex, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

This function made a static position from my table view when I'm reloading data. So just I put this code and the test works correctly.